# Concatenar string em C

Tags: c, string, concatenação-de-string

Boa tarde pessoal, estou iniciando os estudos em `c` e encontrei um problema ao tentar concatenar `strings`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char str1[50], str2[50], str3[50];
    
    printf ("Digite a primeira frase:");
    fgets (str1, 50, stdin);

    printf ("Digite a segunda frase:");
    fgets (str2, 50, stdin);
    
    strcat (str1, str2);
    
    printf ("Frases concatenadas: %s ", str1);
    
}
```

No final o programa imprime o `\n` da primeira `string`, assim o resultado sai como com a segunda `string` em uma linha separada, ao invés de um após o outro, como resolver isso?

Comment: Estude a definição da função fgets que irá constatar que o ou ela irá considerar o número máximo de caracteres discriminado na chamada da função ou irá considerar o caractere '\n' como fazendo parte da string. Uma possibilidade é sobrescrever o caractere '\n' com: `str1[strlen(str1) - 1] = '\0';`.

Answer (score 0):

A função `fgets` lê a string até a quantidade de caracteres ser lida ou até uma nova linha (`\n`) ou EOF ser encontrado. Caso ela encontre um caracter de nova linha, ela o adiciona na String.

Você tem duas opções:

- Você pode usar outra função de leitura (como por exemplo `fscanf`) e adaptar o código para ela.
- Inserir o caracter de término de string exatamente aonde o caracter de nova linha está. Deve-se fazer isso antes de concatenar as duas. Uma forma de fazer isso é:

```
string1[ strcspn( str1, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
string1[ strcspn( str2, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
strcat (str1, str2);
```